# Copying component from src to my app Errors: "Failed to compile." but I am able to modify styles

Tags: overrides, react, compile, scandipwa

I'm trying to customize a few components, but anytime I try to copy a component from `/scandipwa/node_modules/@scandipwa/scandipwa/src/component/Footer/` into my app directory `/scandipwa/src/component/Footer/` I get the following errors:

[image]

I have tried various components and I get the same results. I have tried removing all but the `.component.js` and `.style.scss` files in the directory, but the error still persist.

I do not get any errors with just `.style.scss` files and have been able to override those component files just fine as long as I remove everything else in the component directory.

What might I be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out, and it wasn't easy. I've found that ScandiPWA help out there is pretty limited at best, so hopefully this will help another get started if they run into the same or anything similar.

**Several things going on here:**

First, I needed to configure ESLint: https://docs.scandipwa.com/developing-with-scandi/developer-tools/configuring-eslint

Then I found this tutorial that was very helpful on how to actually set up the file to override it:
https://docs.scandipwa.com/tutorials/video-tutorials/overriding-a-file

What I was doing *wrong* was copying all of the contents of the file over, where instead I needed to *import* the original file and then modify (the only place I could find that explains this is in the video tutorial).

**So, my file now looks like:**

```
/* eslint jsx-quotes: ["error", "prefer-single"] */

import { Footer as SourceFooter } from 'SourceComponent/Footer/Footer.component';

/** @namespace Scandipwa/Component/Footer/Component */

export class FooterComponent extends SourceFooter {
    
      ... render stuff here ...
}

export default FooterComponent;
```

**Important things to note (not in the tutorial or docs, that I could find anyway):**

I was getting "Unexpected usage of singlequote jsx-quotes" errors so found I needed to use this according to these docs: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/jsx-quotes (adding the rule to my json file didn't seem to work, but adding the rule to the file did)
`/* eslint jsx-quotes: ["error", "prefer-single"] */`

The file also needs a namespace defined:
`/** @namespace Scandipwa/Component/Footer/Component */` - I didn't find this in the docs but in a comment on the video tutorial linked above (thanks Arthur V): *import Header but dont export it as default, make a new class and name it with postfix that extends SourceHeader. You also need to provide a namespace...*

Now all errors are gone and I'm able to override the files without issues.